# Login with django rest auth and mongodb

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, django-rest-auth

im very new to python and django. Currently experimenting on django-rest-auth and mongodb.
So, im trying to set up a login and registration page. The registration works , ie save users in the DB, although i have this error

> TypeError at /rest-auth/registration/
> Field 'id' expected a number but got ObjectId('6092cac59ab89b918140dcab').

From what i gathered, i should create a custom user model (or document?) and set a primary key so django does not add one?

Back to the login issue, which is

> ValueError at /rest-auth/login/
> save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.

The POST method does access the right collection in the DB , because i cannot login with invalid credentials.
This error appear once i have successfully (?) logged in.
After searching for a few hours, im nowhere. I found nothing, i dont know why the save() method would be called after a login.

Ill be thankful for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Can't say much without looking at the code. And seems like you have multiple issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Second problem probably comes from the fact that you are trying to save model which has relation to user model but you never propagated user model to the db so it doesn't exist at the time of saving model with relation.

The first one can't say much without looking at the code.

Comment: I solved it by creating a customer user and a custom user manager, then migrating